# Add custom pre-process within the Tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a meta and checkpoint files from which I load the weights of a pre-trained model. This works fine.
To test this model with a new image I need to do some pre-processing for the image (converting from grayscale to RGB, etc) which is basically done using opencv library. Doing this I do get my desired output.

But now what I want to do is add this pre-processing code to tensorflow itself so that when I save this model and re-use it I can only pass the image path as an argument and I don't need to do any pre-processing before passing it to tensorflow. I want tensorflow to handle all this.

I have tried the following already
The following I have used to implement the preprocessing the images within the tensorflow itself and save the new meta and checkpoint files

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    def dataprocess(x):
    #convert from gray to rgb,etc
        return y

    path = ["images/test.jpg"]
    filenames = tf.constant(path)
    dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames))
    dataset = dataset.map(
        lambda path : tf.py_func(
            dataprocess[path], [tf.float32]))
    iterator     = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    next_element = iterator.get_next()
    next_element = tf.reshape(next_element,[-1,3,224,224]) #reshape as tensorflow shows unknown
```

The below code I use to restore my previous model

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess: 
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    element1 = sess.run(next_element)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./.meta')
    saver.restore(sess,'./')

    saver1 = tf.train.Saver()
    input= graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_1:0')
    output= graph.get_tensor_by_name('predictions/Sigmoid:0')
    print(sess.run(output,{input:element1}))
    saver1.save(sess,'/tmp/test1/')
```

This all works fine

Next, I use the newly created meta and checkpoint  files to test for an image(path)

```
path = ["images/test.jpg"]
with tf.Session() as sess: 
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./.meta')
    saver.restore(sess,'./')

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input = graph.get_tensor_by_name('Const:0')
    output= graph.get_tensor_by_name('predictions/Sigmoid:0')
    print(sess.run(output,{input:path}))
```

Using I get the following error

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,3,224,224]
     [[Node: input_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,3,224,224], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

input_1 corresponds to the above input of the graph

So I am assuming I am not passing the path to the correct place

I am new to tensorflow and there is pretty less documentation regarding this

Thank you

Comment: Should `input = graph.get_tensor_by_name('Const:0')` not be `input= graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_1:0')` instead, like it is above?

Comment: thanks for replyin @BlueSun. In that case then I would have to pass the image with shape (?,3,224,224) but i want to pass the image path

Comment: Do you create your network graph yourself or do you load it from a checkpoint? There seems to be a placeholder left somewhere in the graph of your network.

Comment: However there is a bigger problem with your approach (see answer)

Answer (score 1):

> But now what I want to do is add this pre-processing code to
>   tensorflow itself so that when I save this model and re-use it I can
>   only pass the image path as an argument and I don't need to do any
>   pre-processing before passing it to tensorflow. I want tensorflow to
>   handle all this.

Unfortunately this is not possible if you use the `tf.py_func` operation. When you save the graph the python code inside the `tf.py_func` will not be saved as it is not part of the graph. (See `py_func` limitations [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func).) The only way to make the pre-processing part of the graph would be to rewrite it with tensorflow code without using the `tf.py_func`.